# Why android:layout_above does not work

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

My second textview does not appear above the third textview(@+id/date_test).

When I put my second TextView(@+id/category_test) below first TextView(@+id/event_test) it works perfectly.

Can you tell me why it does not appear?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textColor="@color/background_list"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/date_test"
        android:textColor="@color/background_list"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@color/background_list"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the expected result? How you want your view looks like?

Comment: You should define `category_test` **after** `date_test` and refer it so: `android:layout_above="@id/date_test"`. Also remove the **+** from all the other references (since **+** is used to create a NEW id - RARELY used to reference anticipately).

Comment: copy-pasted this layout into IDE - my `category_test` appears above `date_test`. Either you expect something different from what you describe or.. don't know what else could be here :)

Comment: @Rami I expect that Category appear imediately above the Date. And not imediately bellow EventText.

Comment: @PavelDudka I did expect that Category appear imediately above the Date. And not imediately bellow EventText.

Comment: @Der Golem, Thx, I didn't know about the +, I did not know that the order of the views influenced the result. But when I did your modification, the category_test was in place of date, and date disappeared.

Comment: Very strange: `category_test` doesn't have the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` set. So, it should not take the place of `date_test`

Comment: I've also copy-pasted your layout in my IDE, and the view is like you expect. *event_text* on top of the layout, *date_test* on bottom of the layout and *category_test*  imediately abouve *date_test* and not imediately bellow *event_text*. am i wrong?

Comment: What appear here, I guess that it is eclipse bug :(

http://i.imgur.com/wjSc6ia.png?1

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/background_list"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/date_test"
        android:textColor="@color/background_list"
        android:textStyle="bold" />